# Steps before building openCV from a source code

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, installation

first of all I am pretty new in Ubuntu and can't yet understand some details of software installation.
I  need to compile an app from [this repository](https://github.com/HermannHesse/faster_rcnn_cplusplus).
It needs protobuf 3.3.0 which is already installed from a source code. Unfortunately my OpenCV is built with protobuf 2.6.1, so I got an error: `This program was compiled against version 2.6.1 of the Protocol Buffer`
I found [this instruction](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) to build OpenCV form a source, but I already have standard OpenCV.
Could you,please, advice, what steps should i do before this instruction to avoid versions conflicts. Should i somhow clean or delete current openCV ?

Comment: The instruction you post is of a very old opencv. You may need a newer one. To avoid conflicts, set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and `PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR` correctly to your protobuf files or dirs, respectively.

Comment: As @halfelf said that one is quite old, [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/) is one much newer which I used like 5 days ago, also, I recommend to install ccmake, to modify pretty easy the cmake parameters, which probably will let you set the version of the libraries

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem when trying to build OpenCV 3.3 from source with protoc 3.3.2. What solved the problem for me was to first install QT5:

`sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev`

Then you need to remove your existing OpenCV installation and rebuild it from scratch using the `WITH_QT=ON` flag in the cmake command